# File descriptors aren't read by subprocess after .readline()

Tags: python, subprocess

Today I wrote the following script, which doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''
hsort.py
sort, but keeping the header at the top
'''

import sys
from subprocess import Popen
from contextlib import suppress

def main() -> None:
    print(sys.stdin.readline(), end='')
    with suppress(EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        Popen(['sort', *sys.argv[1:]], stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=sys.stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After a significant amount of debugging, I found that subprocess.Popen fails to read any remaining lines from a file object (in this case sys.stdin), if `fd.readline()` has been called previously.

From my knowledge of python (as well as C file pointers), I wasn't able to rationalise either why this would happen, nor why it might be intentionally coded to work this way within the subprocess module.

Is this expected behavior, and is there a simple way to rationalise why this occurs?

Comment: I'd guess it's a buffering issue.

Comment: It certainly _could be_ a buffering issue; if `sys.stdin.readline()` doesn't read byte-by-byte (which is unavoidably slow since it has to do a separate syscall per byte of input, meaning lots of context switches), it _has_ to read in larger chunks, which means it'll consume more than just one line. This is the unavoidable technical constraint behind bash's `read` command being so very slow.

Comment: @PatrickGray, ...btw, you'll see the same problem with readline-esque calls in C: They're either buffered (and so make more content than just the one line unavailable to subprocesses and unbuffered IO), or they're slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You aren't doing anything meaningful with the `Popen()` object that you just created. You will need to call [`.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) or [`.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) on it for the subprocess to actually run to its completion, just like you would need to [`wait(2)`](https://manned.org/wait.2) for a child process created with [`fork(2)`](https://manned.org/fork.2). If you don't, then the child process will most likely just error out as soon as it tries to read anything from its standard input because your script terminated too early and the file descriptor became invalid.
2. The `sys.stdin.readline()` call you are doing before executing `sort` is most likely consuming *more* than a single line of input. If Python's standard input is buffered (which most likely is) then that `.readline()` simply reads an arbitrarily large chunk of data (on my system up to 8KiB) and then processes it to find the first newline character.

   After the first read, `sort` will be started, but there will be nothing else left to read because everything was already read by the initial `.readline()` and stored in some Python's internal buffer for later.

   To solve this you should either avoid reading the first line, or do so in an unbuffered way. This is kind of annoying to do, you'll need to `open()` standard input from its file descriptor again specifying `buffering=0` to get a new "file object" that is unbuffered, and then read every single byte of input manually.

In conclusion, what you want to do is the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from subprocess import Popen

def main() -> None:
    first_line = b''

    with open(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', closefd=False, buffering=0) as f:
        while not first_line.endswith(b'\n'):
            first_line += f.read(1)

    print(first_line.decode(), end='')

    p = Popen(['sort', *sys.argv[1:]], stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=sys.stdout)
    p.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think `sort` will only terminate when it tries to write to the pipe whose other end is closed by the exiting Python script, not simply because the script exits.

Comment: @chepner hm you're right, though still strictly speaking that's not a pipe in this case, just the old invalid descriptor of the deceased parent. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, are you quite sure that `sys.stdin.readline()` is taking the performance hit to do an unbuffered byte-by-byte read to only consume one line and read the rest queued up for future processes? If not, I would expect some content to still be discarded (being in Python's buffer for future reads, and not accessible to `sort`).

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: So to summarise, `fd.readline()` uses a different buffer to that used by subprocess? I think that's the aspect I wasn't expecting, which explains why my code doesn't work.

Comment: `file.readline()` uses the buffer provided by the file object `file` (it can have a buffer or not, it depends on the case, `sys.stdin` is buffered). When you launch a subprocess it's up to that program to do whatever it wants, you shouldn't really care, but the problem is that if you already read part of the input from the file, that subprocess isn't going to be able to read it as it has already been consumed. With buffered files, this is tricky because you may think `readline()` only reads up to one line, but it does not: it reads more data and then returns the first line.